# Target Encoding in Python Model

Tags: encoding, target

I made a model in python and this uses target encoding. I used a dataset with 25000 rows and this gets divided into training and test data sets. The model is really working fine. However, I now want to run the model on totally fresh data - say just one row of data in an excel file. I need to know the code for it and will really appreciate it if someone can help. I am somewhat new to python.  Here is the part of code I have written to create the training and test data sets from 25000 rows and train the model on training and predict on the test. However, I need the code that runs this model that uses target encoding to predict fresh data. If I need to post more code for greater clarity please let me know.

```
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(train_x.values, train_y.values)

pred_train = rf.predict(train_x.values)
pred = rf.predict(test_x.values)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have have a look the comment section in this notebook-
[here](https://www.kaggle.com/ogrellier/python-target-encoding-for-categorical-features)

"After we apply target encoding on the train data and target. We can have the result for one category like column A has a,b,c. Then we calculate the mean of each a,b,c in column A and apply it to the test data.We then apply it to test using the pd.merge function."